# Why the difference between the determinant formulas in Russian and English Wikipedia versions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

The article [Determinant](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C#%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B_%7F'%22%60UNIQ--postMath-00000031-QINU%60%22'%7F) in Russian version of the Wikipedia tell us that determinant might be found as:

$$\Delta = \sum^n_{j=1}(-1)^{i+j}a_{ij}M^{-i}_j$$

In the [English version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Laplace's_formula_and_the_adjugate_matrix), the formula is slightly different:

$$\det(A) = \sum^n_{j=1}(-1)^{i+j}a_{i,j}M_{i,j}$$

Could someone, please, explain why the Russian version's sum takes only *j-th* minor **M**'s element and has minus *i* power, but the English version has only a single element (*i,j*)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Russian version does not show
$$M_j^{-i} $$
but rather
$$\bar M_j^i $$
and even explains

> где ${\bar {M}}_{j}^{1}$ — дополнительный минор к элементу $a_{1j}$

which is hence just a different notation for the same thing

Answer (score 1):

The Russian version shows particular cases:
$$\Delta = \sum^n_{j=1}(-1)^{1+j}a_{1j}\bar{M}^1_j \ \ - \ \text{expansion by the first row elements}$$
$$\Delta = \sum^n_{i=1}(-1)^{i+1}a_{i1}\bar{M}^i_1 \ \ - \ \text{expansion by the first column elements}$$
And then it gives the general formula of expansion by any row (column):
$$\Delta = \sum^n_{j=1}(-1)^{i+j}a_{ij}\bar{M}^i_j \ \ (\text{for a fixed $i$})$$
Also, note it is not a minus $i$ power, but a complementary minor: $\bar{M}^{\ \ i}_{\ \ j}$.